# Passing and URL as parameter in mod-rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to pass an URL as a parameter in mod-rewrite. I guess there is a problem in my Regex. This my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule **^go/((http:\/\/)+[A-Za-z0-9\-]+[\.A-Za-z])/?$** feedmini.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

the URL I want to pass looks like *http://www.aaaa.com/aaa/?q=v* but when ever I try to reach it on go/http://www.aaaa.com/aaa/?q=v I get an 404 error page. I've also tried with `**^go/([A-Za-z0-9\-\/:]+[\.A-Za-z]+)/?$**` but then the URL i pass gets like this: http:/www.aaaa.com/aaa/  (observe the singel '/' after 'http:');

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance
/Ale

Comment: Do you mean that your URLs are like `http://example.com/go/http://stackoverflow.com/`?

Comment: Hi Tim!

Yeah, that's exactly what I want to accomplish, but I havent got any positive results yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your first problem (in your first code block) is that your Regex pattern will not match a URL since it will only match a string that begins with http:// then contains nothing but alphanum or dashes, which ends with a single fullstop or letter. Perhaps this is simply a typo and there should be a quantifier in there, but even so it would fail to match a very large percentage or URLs.

This may seem a little strange, but try this...

```
RewriteRule ^go/http:/(.*)/?$ feedmini.php?url=http://$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Note that the `/?` at the end will never match, because the `.*` will grab the trailing slash greedily if it's there (which is fine). Also, +1, since this is the right answer. Any number of multiple slashes will be condensed into a single slash before being passed to the `RewriteRule` test pattern.

Comment: Good point Tim, I guess I'm just used to writing /? at the end of my patterns :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! Its working perfect now. I think I should learn more about Regex ;)