# mod_rewrite to match URL as parameter

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to pass a full unescaped URL as a parameter, like so:

```
http://domain-a.com/http://domain-b.com/
```

I've achieved this using the technique outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481424/passing-and-url-as-parameter-in-mod-rewrite), which suggested the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^http:/(.*)/?$ http://domain-a.com/index.php?u=http://$1 [L,NE,QSA]
```

While I know this is something of a hack (given that the second URL should be encoded), I would like to know if it is possible to allow the same mod_rewrite rule to accept and pass along query strings, like so:

```
http://domain-a.com/http://domain-b.com/?sort=new
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's impossible to do that, because how would mod_rewrite know whether the querystring was for domain-a or should be rewritten as a part of the domain-b url?

Comment: That's actually fine, in this case. Provided the query string is stapled onto the redirect URL, I'm happy. I'm not looking to distinguish between domain-a or domain-b.